# camel ftp route and file type converters

Tags: apache-camel

I am struggling with type conversion in my camel route for handling ftp files. My route looks like this (in Spring DSL):

```
<route id="processIncomingFtpFile" errorHandlerRef="parkingCitErrHandler">
      <from uri="{{ftp.parkingcit.input.path}}"/>
      <bean ref="ftpZipFileHandler"/>
      <unmarshal ref="bindyCsvFormat"/>
      <bean ref="parkingTicketsHandler"/>
      <split>
          <simple>${body}</simple>
          <marshal ref="jaxbFormatter"/>
          <convertBodyTo type="java.io.File"/>
      <to uri="{{ftp.parkingcit.output.path}}"/>
      </split>
   </route>
```

And my handler signature looks like this:

```
public File handleIncomingFile(File incomingfile)...
```

However, this yields the following type conversion problem:

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.File but has value: RemoteFile[test.zip] of type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile on: test.zip. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile to the required type: java.io.File with value RemoteFile[test.zip]. Exchange[test.zip]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile to the required type: java.io.File with value RemoteFile[test.zip]]
```

My question is: should I be able to handle my ftp file in-memory, without explicitly telling camel to write it to disk, with type converters doing the work automagically behind the scenes for me? Or is what I am trying to do senseless, given that my handler wants a java.io.File as its input parameter, i.e. I must write the data to disk for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.io.File is for file systems, and not for FTP files.

You would need to change the type in your bean method signature to either Camel's GenericFile or the actual type which is from the commons-net FTP client library that Camel uses.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I would recommend to work with a local file (I always do that with the ftp endpoint). There is an option in the ftp endpoint called localWorkDirectory that lets you define a directory to download the file ( typically, /tmp ) before further processing. The idea is to avoid any error due to network issue or being disconnected during process
Can you try it It's easy enough (just add &localWorkDirectory =mydir in the uri ) and it will dl the file for you
see https://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html.
Just make sure you have write right on the directory, of course

Comment: That's not exactly what I was trying to do, per se, but it will get the job done I suppose. Thanks.